# How to deploy a contract using web3@1.0.0-beta.51 and solc@0.5.7

Tags: solidity, web3js

I want to write some tests using mocha and ganache-cli for my contract. I tried to deploy a compiled contract like so:

```
//ZombieFactory.test.js

const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());

const compiledZombieFactory = require('../ethereum/build/ZombieFactory.json');

let accounts;
let factory;

beforeEach(async () => {
    accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    factory = await new web3.eth.Contract(compiledZombieFactory.abi)
        .deploy({data: '0x' + compiledZombieFactory.evm.bytecode.object})
        .send({from: accounts[0], gas: '3000000'});

});

describe('ZombieFactory', () => {
    it('deploys the zombie factory', () => {
        assert.ok(factory.options.address);
    })
});
```

When I run this using `npm run test`, I get the following error:

```
ZombieFactory
    1) "before each" hook for "deploys the zombie factory"


  0 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) "before each" hook for "deploys the zombie factory":
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

I did some research and I suppose this error occurs because the code fails to deploy the contract successfully.
I would like to know if this issue is due to the deploy code or something else.

Comment: I also error too. How can i fix it?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35499)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution!

web3@1.0.0-beta.51 is not that stable. Use the most stable release (as of now as version 1.0 is still in beta).

So basically:
Uninstall `npm uninstall web3@1.0.0-beta.51`

Install `npm install --save web3@1.0.0-beta.37`

The same code runs without throwing any errors :)

Answer (score 2):

`ganache-cli` is a bit to deprecated at this point. It is recommended to use truffle develop which replaces ganache-cli and supports latest Solidity versions.

You can find out a lot more from this awesome guy:

```
// Truffle Toolkit + Truffle Scripts
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6DzzeoRTS0&t=623s

// Actual Testing
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v90hvMEjf_Q
```

Good Luck !

Comment: I realized that working with latest versions of all packages without using a suite like truffle isn't a good idea. I started using truffle and everything works great now. Thanks buddy!